# Azure Functions: Is there optimal way to upload file without storing it in process memory?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload file to blob container via HTTP.

On request receiving file through:

```
public class UploadFileFunction
{
    //Own created wrapper on BlobContainerClient 
    private readonly IBlobFileStorageClient _blobFileStorageClient;

    public UploadFileFunction(IBlobFileStorageClient blobFileStorageClient)
    {
        _blobFileStorageClient = blobFileStorageClient;
    }

    [FunctionName("UploadFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "/equipments/{route}")]
        HttpRequest request,
        [FromRoute] string route)
    {
        IFormFile file = request.Form.Files["File"];
        if (file is null)
        {
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }

        string fileNamePath = $"{route}_{request.Query["fileName"]}_{request.Query["fileType"]}";
        BlobClient blob = _blobFileStorageClient.Container.GetBlobClient(fileNamePath);

        try
        {
            await blob.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = file.ContentType });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new ConflictResult();
        }

        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

Than making request with file:
[image]

On UploadAsync whole stream of the file is uploaded in process memory
[image]

Is exists some way to upload directly to blob without uploading in process memory?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, you can determine memory usage problems on your dev machine while running the debug version of the program in a debugger?? I hope you know, that GC won't clean up as long as there is enough free space and you do stuff in a tight loop (like uploading chunks of bytes), especially if you are only talking about 80MB (on a dev machine) and the debugger should probably visualize a bunch of variables and co to you. Have you tried to push 4GB through it? Did you try the VS Memory Profiler? I think, these would give you more meaningful values.

Comment: @Oliver azure functions have constraint on upload and this is 100mb. Of course it's not critical. But multiple requests are possible which will consume more memory. I will try your suggest about debug level and also VS Memory Profiler. TY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to avoid this is to not upload your file via your own HTTP endpoint at all. Asking how to avoid the uploaded data not ending up in the process memory (via an HTTP endpoint) makes no sense.

Simply use the [Azure Blob Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api) to directly upload this file to the Azure blob storage. Your own HTTP endpoint simply needs to issue a [Shared access signature (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) token for a file upload and the client can upload the file directly to the Blob storage.

This pattern should be used for file uploads unless you have a very good reason not to. Your trigger function is only called after the HTTPRunTime is finished with the HTTP request, hence the trigger's HttpRequest object is allocated in the process memory which is then passed to the trigger.

I also suggest [block blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs) if you want to upload in multiple stages.

Comment: I knew about sas, it's another approach that I am using for files bigger than 100mb. Also I simply using Azure Blob Storage REST API to uploadAsync. The question is "is exists way to upload via http azure function without allocation".

Comment: The pattern I explained should be used for file uploads unless you have a very good reason not to. I think it is safe to say that the answer to your question is no. Your trigger function is only called after the HTTPRunTime is finished with the HTTP request, hence the trigger's HttpRequest object is allocated in the process memory which has the request's body data and then passed to the trigger.

Comment: Great explain, I guess could admit your answer as solving of the problem. Could you please edit your answer with that commentary for others whose would be interested in that question? Thank you

Comment: The SAS token solution seems to forgo the opportunity to enforce metadata requirements or other content restrictions upon upload. The process is left with what ever the SAS token user uploaded. I realize this in not part of the OPs original request, but it seems to be an implication of the strategy.

Comment: @WillEtson Unless your requirement is to do everything in a single HTTP call, you can use Blob storage Triggers or Event Hub triggers to enforce restrictions, perform scans, compliance etc. for any data uploaded from a user.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the default way UploadAsync works, this will be ok for files that are small.  I ran into an out of memory issue with large files; the solution here is to use [AppendBlobAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.appendblobclient.appendblockasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview)

You will need to create the blob as an append blob, so you can keep appending to end of the blob. Basic gist is:

1. Create an append blob
2. Go through the existing file and grab xMB(say 2 MB) chunks at a time
3. Append these chunks to the append blob until the end of file

pseudo code something like below

```
var appendBlobClient = _blobFileStorageClient.GetAppendBlobClient(fileNamePath);
await appendBlobClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var appendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes = appendBlobClient.AppendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes;

using (var file = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    int bytesRead;
    var buffer = new byte[appendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes];
    while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        //Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        var newArray = new Span<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead).ToArray();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(newArray);
        stream.Position = 0;
        appendBlobClient.AppendBlock(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually the question is how to avoid memory allocation in memory process. I don't face with out of memory issue. Because functions has a constrain on file upload to 100mb. As I use azure functions which are serverless I will pay for the code time  execution, cpu and memory. So I trying to find out how to stream data from request directly to blob without uploading in process.

Comment: I would avoid using Append Blob to solve this problem. Append Blobs are special kind of blobs optimized to store logs etc.

Comment: Actually @GauravMantri it won't solve my problem. Moreover, it is increasing memory usage.

Comment: Aah ok I misunderstood the question; looks like Mo's answer is correct in that case